# Trouble reading from file and writing to an array

Tags: arrays

I need to read a file and store the data in an array by looping through the file and identifying the line in the file by a string "humanities" and then store the number of students in an Array as well as the gender of class

txt file:

Humanities: m, 10

String[] stringArray = getLine().split(":");
                if(stringArray[0].equals("Humanities")){

```
            String[] SchoolArray = stringArray[1].split(",");
            char gender = (schoolArray[0]).charAt(0);
            int number = new Integer(schoolArray[1]).intValue();

            doctorArray.add(number);
```

it comes up with the error can't invoke char and int on the array type String

Comment: A few errors... and questions. 1. What lang? (I assume java) 2. You should probably trim the elements in schoolArray -> schoolArray[0] is " m". So charAt would return " ". 3. What is doctorArray? 4. I cleaned this code up and ran it locally.. Worked just fine once I fixed spelling and the other issues I spoke of.

Comment: Java and what and doctorArray should be SchoolArray.add(gender, number) what do you mean by question 2? can you show me the new code

Comment: Basically the stringArray[1].split(",") will give you an array like -> String[] { " m", " 10" }. If you leave it like that and do schoolArray[0].charAt(0) you will get ' ' since it is looking at the 1st spot in the string. if you do trim you will get "m" and the charAt lookup will net 'm'. Similar to number -> " 10" will fail when converting to an int. You need to run " 10".trim() to get rid of the extra white space.

Answer (score 0):

Here is just the section of code: I can edit if it's not what you were looking for.

```
String str = "Humanities: m, 10";
String[] stringArray = str.split(":");
if(stringArray[0].equals("Humanities")){
    String[] schoolArray = stringArray[1].split(",");
    char gender = (schoolArray[0].trim()).charAt(0);
    int number = Integer.parseInt(schoolArray[1].trim());
    System.out.println("gender: " + gender + ", number: " + number);
}
```

Comment: I need to read from a txt file stored in the directory so the first line isn't what i'm looking for. Then instead of printing out i need to store gender and number in an Array

Comment: Your question sounded like you were erroring out in this chunk of code. You can read the lines in like: http://kodejava.org/how-do-i-read-all-lines-from-a-file/ and then you would run the code that I posted above within a foreach loop or some sort of looping construct replacing "str" with each item from the list. Then you would add the println stuff to a list. You can't add 2 elements side by side in a list. You would have to wrap them up in another Object/Tuple or combine them in a string. Then convert that to an array to return it. Everything you need is already out there. Give it a shot.